# como deixar o focus desativado em uma janela mesmo que eu clique nela?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Estou programando um teclado virtual, onde vou digitar clicando com o mouse.
Em python2.7 interface qt4
Já consegui resolver bastante a ideia, consegui fazer ele ficar sempre aparecendo, e também fazer ele digitar em qualquer outra janela..
O problema é que ele só esta digitando quando clico em uma input de outra janela, só depois de teclar.
Preciso que ele mantenha o focus false, mesmo clicando nele e que as outras janelas tenham o controle do focus.
Isso é possivel?

PS o codigo

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import pyautogui
import time



form_class = uic.loadUiType("Form1.ui")[0]


class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setupUi(self)


        #   
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)
        #self.btnEntrar.clicked.connect(self.btnEntrar_clicked)
        #self.btnEntrar2.clicked.connect(self.btnEntrar2_clicked)

    def btn1_clicked(self):
        #print "teste"
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.typewrite("Teste 1, 2, 3...")
```

Comment: Mostre o código atual para que possa ser checado onde está o problema.

Comment: pronto, coloquei o codigo lá